# Finding an example for a group operation on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

An operation of a group $G$ on a set $S$ is a rule $G \times S \to S$. Suppose we have $G=C_3 \times C_5 = C_{15}$, and $S$ is a set with $4$ elements. I think we can partition $S$ into orbits $O_1$ and $O_2$ with $|O_1| = 1$ and $|O_2| = 3$. By the counting formula, the stabilizer of $O_1$ has order $15$ and the stabilizer of $O_2$ has order $5$. Is that reasoning correct? How can we find an example where this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the concept you are looking for is [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)) on a set.

If the set is finite, all group action on it amounts to permuting the elements of the set.  So, all that is needed is to associate, homomorphically, to each element of $C_{15}$ a permutation of 
$$
S = \{s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}, s_{4}\}.
$$
So, if $c$ is a generator of the cyclic group $C_{15}$, let's assign to it the permutation
$$
(s_{1}) \quad ( s_{2} \;  s_{3} \; s_{4}).
$$
It fixes $s_{1}$ and cyclically permutes the other elements of $S$.  Now you can compute the permutations corresponding to $c^2, c^3, $ etc..